# Raster NoData Value

Tags: raster, nodata, data-management

So over the years working with elevation and image rasters in various formats I always kind of ignore the value of **No Data**. I usually just let the software/vendor/someone else decide on the value for me. Lately I've been giving it some thought. Why am I using this arbitrary software assigned value of:

- -3.40282306074e+038 *(I assume the lowest possible float number)*
- 255,255,255 *(white)*
- 0,0,0 *(black)*
- -255

Now I'm in a large process of organising and optimising our raster datasets. These datasets are elevation, analysis and aerial photography. And I am finding now is a good time to set a consistent **No Data** value. Personally I am thinking of using the following:

- **Elevation:** -1
- **Air Photography:** -1, -1, -1
- **Analysis:** -1 (when possible, does not work for all datasets)

Concerning Elevation and Air Photo raster, will setting -1 really mess up analysis done on the dataset, will it display properly and does No Data really even matter?

I've done a few tests and everything seems to work out, but are there any long term implications that I need to worry about?

Comment: there are negative elevation (e.g. polders in the Netherlands, the dead sea...) so you should avoid -1.

Comment: I'm in Ontario, so I really had not thought of that. It appears the [lowest exposed land on Earth is at the Dead Sea shore, at -413 meters](https://geology.com/below-sea-level/). So I believe I should adjust my -1 to a -1000. Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget the more usual -9999 as a no data value.

Comment: I´d say decide *in situ*: an actual value may be taken into account for any statistical analysis if not specified while *NoData* may not be supported by all formats/tools, both have advantages over the other in terms of visualization and so on.

Comment: If you want universal value then I would use -9999 which is apparently not real value and it is easy to replace it later with something other according to particular task.

Comment: NoData values (apart from the frequently used -999(9)) tend to just be the positive or negative extremes of the data type range. Easy enough to remember/work out. I think you're overthinking this and may trip yourself up in various subtle ways (i.e -1 is a valid elevation, using -1 for aerial photography will double the file size, assuming uncompressed 8bit RGB)

Comment: @Luke I am definitely overthinking it, but I have a chance to set a standard for the way we store our raster datasets. I want to ensure I made logical good decisions. In terms of air photos I didn't even think of the doubling in size for -1! That's a huge mistake if I went that route. Thus far I am using -9999 for elevation and analytical rasters. Hadn't got to air photos yet, but I am going to have to re think it.

Comment: And don't forget there's more to NoData than just values, you can also have alpha channels/mask bands ;)